# Clear browser cache for load renamed file

Tags: javascript, php, image, caching

I have some images in a folder that I rename (like 1000.jpg 2000.jpg...) with PHP script and when PHP return to html the images don't have been reloaded in the right order, instead of what's happened in directory. How can i clear browser cache from file and image without using Chrome standard function in PHP or javascript?

something like this

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

or like

```
location.reload(true)
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<img src="1000.jpg?<?php echo(time());?>">
```